# Primary CME Publisher doesn't work when we use a scaled out publisher in another machine with a filter

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1

I'm trying to make use of scaled out publisher newly installed on separate CME and set the filter to pick only **LOW priority items**.

Now, when I publish any item from my primary publisher with priority other than "LOW", the transaction gets stuck at "Waiting for Publish".
When published with "LOW" priority, then this gets published successfully as expected. This is getting picked up by my secondary server.

When I stop the publisher service in the secondary CME, then the primary works completely fine.

Please let me understand how I can make my primary server also work when both the publishers services are up?

Comment: Is your 'Primary' Publisher configured to filter on priorities (i.e. Just Medium and High (4;6)), or is filtering disabled (meaning that it should pick everything up)?

Comment: Also, I presume that you are trying to publish exactly the same item(s) when you are testing this? If not, then it may be that there is difference in the templating code (e.g. the Razor Mediator version) available to each.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why the two publishers shouldn't work fine together. It's particularly odd that stopping the secondary publisher makes the primary work OK.

When a publisher service stops or starts, it updates its record in the QUEUE_CONSUMERS table in the Content Manager database. (One reason why it's handy to stop your publishers before taking backups that are intended to be restored elsewhere.)

I would suggest that you look at the contents of the QUEUE_CONSUMERS table, and how it changes when you start and stop the service. For a complete picture, I'd also look in QUEUE_FILTERS.

With a bit of luck, this will give you some insights into what's going wrong. (I know this sounds crazy, but have you checked they haven't got the same hostname?)

Comment: Thanks Dominic for you response.I'm using two different hostnames for both my servers.Is there any way we can find out from which publisher service the item was published?

Comment: And can you see records for both hostnames in QUEUE_CONSUMERS?

Comment: Yes.I can see both the host names.